# Rich Text Editor That Can Strip Microsoft Word Formatting?

Tags: cakephp, formatting, ms-word, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I'm building a (CakePHP) website with an admin section that allows rich text editing of some of the entered data.  Currently I'm using TinyMCE but I'm not sure if there isn't a better tool for the job, given some of the requirements (or at least would-be-very-nice-to-haves) of the client.

Ideally, if a user were to cut and paste content from Microsoft Word, this would automatically lose its formatting and be pasted as plaintext.  Can TinyMCE strip formatting from all pasted text, as it is being pasted?  Or is there another rich text editor that is notably good at doing this?  Or an option three?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're using the "pastetext" and "pasteword" option in TinyMCE (to give the users the option to paste text-only or try to use all formatting) and it works pretty good.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste

Answer (score 3):

I use CkeEditor. Here is a helper for it:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/wernerhp/2010/08/31/cksource-helper-for-ckeditor

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting, going to have to try that out at some point!